# PHP Pthreads not able to pass values to child objects within the threads

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

So, I have about 100+ processes that I would like to make parallely executed. I am using PHP pthreads to do that.

The problem I have is that the threads start but they do not pass values to another object which is initialized within the thread. What I would like to do is the execute each of those child process in separate objects.

#### updated code

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define('DEBUG', true);

function pr($var) {
   if (!DEBUG) {
       return;
   }

   echo PHP_EOL;

   if ($var) {
      print_r($var);
   } else {
      var_dump($var);
   }

   echo PHP_EOL;
}

class A {

   //public $results = 1;

   function init() {
      pr(__CLASS__ . ' initailized');
   }

   function getResult() {
       return ($this->results);
   }
}

class B extends A {

   public $val;
   public $results = [
       'queries' => []
   ];

   function set($k, $v) {
      $this->{$k} = $v;
   }

   function init() {
      pr(__CLASS__ . ' initailized');
      parent::init();

      $this->results = ['some_value' => true];
   }
}

class Fetching extends Thread {

    function __construct() {

    }

   public function run() {
      $this->e = new B;
      $this->e->init();

      pr($this->e->getResult());
   }
}

$data = [
   'id' => 12345,
   'message' => 'some text here'
];

$thread = new Fetching();

$thread->start();
$thread->join();
pr($thread);
```

When I run $thread->results it outputs as NULL. But if I make it a string or int it works just fine.

Comment: It's at least formally wrong not to invoke the baseclass' constructor from your constructor. That said, you don't start any threads here, since `$processes_list` is empty!?

Comment: Does `$this->queries` contain the desired value just before thread ends? And of what type is that value?

Comment: $this->queries is an array containing mysql queries. The thread runs but does not return the array of $this->queries.

Comment: *// pass the mysql queries back to thread* <- I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you post more code?

Comment: This is not executable code, without executable code, everyone is guessing ... Reduce the problem to it's simplest form, forget your objects and current application and illustrate the problem with as little generic code as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. But I am not quite sure if its a correct behaviour. Your suggestions are welcome...

What I was doing is creating a class variable `$this->e` and assigning it the child process object `$this->e = new $object` and then running the `init()` method. The init method returns a few queries back as class member variable i.e. `$this->e->queries` will have those queries assigned to it. The fix I found is that I should use it as a separate variable within the ['run'](http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php) method of the [Thread Object.](http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php) Not as a class variable and Once I have the queries I can assign it to the class variable directly and call it after doing `$thread->join()` like `$thread->queries` and it works fine.

In short - The class variables of the class extending to Thread does not support Objects within the `run` method.

For more details below is the sample code. I have created two files. 1. Objects.php containing all objects and another one Processor.php. See below.

#### Objects.php contains follow code.

```
<?php

class Controller {

   public $queries = [];

   public function init() {

   }

   public function set($key, $value) {
       $this->{$key} = $value;
       return $this;
   }

   function __destruct() {
       global $scriptStartTime;
       pr("Time taken for " . get_called_class() . " to execute = " .. executionTime($scriptStartTime, true));
   }
}

class SampleObject extends Controller {

  public function init() {
      parent::init();
      sleep(rand(0, 15));
      return $this->queries[] = 'INSERT INTO my_table (something) VALUES ("' . get_called_class() . '")';
  }
}

function pr($array) {
   echo PHP_EOL;
   print_r($array);
   echo PHP_EOL;
}

function executionTime($startTime, $text = false) {
   $time = @number_format(microtime(true) - $startTime, 3);

   $txt = 'seconds';

   if ($time > 60) {
      $time = @number_format($time / 60, 3);
      $txt = 'minutes';
   }

   if ($text) {
      $time = "{$time} {$txt}";
   }

   return $time;
}
```

#### Processor.php contains below code

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Objects.php';

################ Processor #################

class Processor extends \Thread {

    public function __construct($process) {
       $this->process = $process;
    }

    public function run() {
       //\Core\Autoloader::reload(); // reloading all autoloaders
       require __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Objects.php';
       $scriptStartTime = microtime(true);

       # Dynamically creating objects for testing purpose.
       if (!class_exists($this->process['className'])) {
           eval("class " . $this->process['className'] . " extends SampleObject {}");
    }

       $object = (new $this->process['className']);

       # Set the default values that are common across all elements
       $object
            # Identity of thread
            ->set('name', $this->process['className'])
            # Options to carry the assigned values
            ->set('options', $this->process['options'])
            # The project details
            ->set('project', $this->project)
          ;

          $object->init();

          $this->queries = ($object->queries);
     }
}

$scriptStartTime = microtime(true);

for ($i = 0; $i < 150; $i++) {
  $jobs[] = [
      'className' => 'Object_' . $i,
      'options' => []
  ];
}

$totalJobsToExecute = count($jobs);

$i = 0;

# Initalizing threads

$threads = [];

$project = [
   'id' => 12345,
   'title' => 'Some cool stuff'
];

foreach ($jobs AS $process) {
   $i++;

   $proc = $process['className'];
   $threads[$proc] = new Processor($process);
   // In this sample code it works without PTHREADS_INHERIT_NONE, but with my code it doesn't    
   if ($threads[$proc]->start(PTHREADS_INHERIT_NONE)) {
      pr('Thread "' . $process['className'] . '" started');
   }
}

pr("Threads | Starting time = " . executionTime($scriptStartTime, true));

$queries = [];

foreach ($threads AS $thread) {
    if ($thread->join()) {
        $queries[] = $thread->queries;
    }
}

pr($queries);

pr('Count of threads === ' . count($threads));
pr("Threads time = " . executionTime($scriptStartTime, true));
pr("Threads | Total Threads executed = ({$i}) out of (" . $totalJobsToExecute . ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's your problem:

```
$threads[$i]->start(PTHREADS_INHERIT_NONE);
```

You might need [`PTHREADS_INHERIT_CLASSES`](http://php.net/pthreads.constants) to be able to access the class `ChildProcess`.

---

Because of the zend_heap error (I can't reproduce it): Which version of PHP and pthreads are you using?

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.5.27 and pthreads v2. If I don't use PTHREADS_INHERIT_NONE I get zend_heap_error. Could it be because I have a lot of objects preloaded? What I am doing is unregistering and registering my autoloader object within the run method and it works fine. It autoloads the Childprocess class.